# Store indexes of each element of list in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to store indexes of each element of array which have repeated number in python using dictionary.

```
arr=[1,1,3,2,2]
```

desired output should be `{1:0,1:1,3:2,2:3,2:4}`
instead of that index of previous element overwriten by new elemnt index giving `{1:1,3:2,2:4}`

Comment: Keys in a dictionary are unique, you can't have two entries with the same key.

Comment: What would be the result of indexing the desired output by the key ``2``?

Comment: If you need duplicate index of the same numbers, consider defaultdict then.

Answer (score 0):

As Nir H. commented on your question, I am also informing you that **keys in a dictionary must be unique**,i.e you can't have a dictionary like this `{10:0,10:1}`
So what would be a better solution would be to use the indexes as keys and the values of the list at those index be the values of the dictionary. So this would be the end result in your case:
`{0:1, 1:1, 2:3, 3:2, 4:2}` so here the keys are the index and the values are the elements of the list.
To achieve this:

```
arr=[1,1,3,2,2]
dct=dict()
for in in range(len(arr)):
    dct[i]=arr[i]
print(dct)
```

Output:
`{0:1, 1:1, 2:3, 3:2, 4:2}`
This would be the answer to your question.
But I really don't get what You are trying to achieve by storing the indexes and their corresponding elements in a dictionary. Seems redundant and unnecessary.